# ShowMessage works but application.messagebox dont

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

```
ShowMessage('MAC  - (Client: '
        + DM.qTmp.FieldByName('CL_NR').AsString + ' , Place: ' + DM.qTmp.FieldByName('CL_DESC').AsString);
```

This code works fine, but how i can do that with

```
Application.MessageBox('MAC  - (Client: '
            + DM.qTmp.FieldByName('CL_NR').AsString + ' , Place: ' + DM.qTmp.FieldByName('CL_DESC').AsString' , 'Error', 16);
```

Got various errors
[dcc32 Error] untPCName.pas(79): E2010 Incompatible types: 'PWideChar' and 'string'
DELPHI version is 10.2.

Comment: "Got various errors" - List them :O

Comment: Which Delphi version? VCL or FMX?

Comment: Only gangstas use hard coded literal values rather than named constants for bit flags

Comment: Delphi version is 10.2, edited question for errors

Comment: What do you think that *E2010 Incompatible types: 'PWideChar' and 'string'* means?

Comment: That's **one** error. You mentioned "various". Are there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the "Incompatible types" errors you have to cast. Notice the `PChar(...)`:

```
Application.MessageBox(PChar('Whatever'), 'Error', MB_ICONHAND);
```

I also replaced the magic number 16 with something sensible.